# Difficulty in displaying large number of values on a Chart

Tags: sql, sql-server, dotnethighcharts

I am trying to display some records from a database on a chart. The records saved within one minute is usually about 70 records. That number of records would look insane on a line chart, yet it would be more insane and unrealistic to expect users to keep requesting to view records per minute when their data interest is between a four hours interval.

I decided to to group the records by minute, there I got stuck in the query.
Below is my query sample:

```
SELECT DISNTINCT YEAR(recievedon), MONTH(recievedon), DAY(recievedon), HOUR(recievedon), referenceprice
FROM dbname
WHERE recievedon >= '2015-06-05 10:30' AND recievedon <= '2015-06-05 10:50'
ORDER BY recievedon
```

How do I group the records by minute either using `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`

Secondly, is there a better way to render a large dataset in a (line) chart instead of grouping the records?

Comment: Please edit your question and tag it with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were to guess that you were using MySQL, then you can do use `to_seconds()`.  The following gives the average reference price for each minute, along with the date/time of the first price in the interval:

```
select min(recievedon), avg(referenceprice)
from dbname
where recievedon >= '2015-06-05 10:30' AND recievedon <= '2015-06-05 10:50'
group by floor(to_seconds(receivedon) / 60)
```

EDIT:

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
select min(receivedon), avg(referenceprice)
from dbname
where recievedon >= '2015-06-05 10:30' AND recievedon <= '2015-06-05 10:50'
group by datediff(minute, 0, receivedon);
```

If you want the beginning of the period rather than the earlier timestamp:

```
select dateadd(minute, 0, datediff(minute, 0, receivedon)) as timeperiod,
       avg(referenceprice)
from dbname
where recievedon >= '2015-06-05 10:30' AND recievedon <= '2015-06-05 10:50'
group by dateadd(minute, 0, datediff(minute, 0, receivedon)) ;
```

Comment: I run your first edit, I got the following error:
"The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart".

Comment: I ran the second sql it gave me the same error as the first.

Comment: @Chibuzo . . . You know, the expression can be in minutes rather than seconds.

Comment: Okay. The first query works, but the referenceprice is the same for all the found rows.

Comment: The second query throws the following error: "Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime."

Comment: You can always use `2000-01-01` instead of `0` for the constant in these expressions.  That should fix the overflow problem.

Comment: I did this:

"select dateadd(minute, 2000-01-01, datediff(minute, 2000-01-01, recievedon)) as timeperiod,
       avg(referenceprice)
from [dbcloud].[dbo].[tb_securitystatistics]
where recievedon >= '2015-06-05 10:30' AND recievedon <= '2015-06-05 10:50'
group by dateadd(minute, 2000-01-01, datediff(minute, 2000-01-01, recievedon)) ;" It still gave me the same overflow error.

Comment: @Chibuzo . . . You need single quotes around any string that represents a date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84407/discussion-between-chibuzo-and-gordon-linoff).

Answer (score 1):

Using simple group by `DATEPART` without the care of the overflow. The `SELECT` is just the same with Gordon's answer.

```
SELECT 
    MIN(ReceivedOn) AS Time,
    -- Assuming you need average price
    AVG(ReferencePrice) AS ReferencePrice
FROM
    dbname
WHERE
    ReceivedOn BETWEEN '2015-06-05 10:30' AND '2015-06-05 10:50'
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(YEAR, ReceivedOn),
    DATEPART(MONTH, ReceivedOn),
    DATEPART(DAY, ReceivedOn),
    DATEPART(HOUR, ReceivedOn),
    DATEPART(MINUTE, ReceivedOn)
```